# Consecutive interface function IDs

Tags: windows, com, midl

I have a COM object interface in midl like

```
interface InterfaceName : IDispatch
{
  [id(1)] HRESULT FunA(...);
  [id(2)] HRESULT FunB(...);
  [id(3)] HRESULT FunC(...);
}
```

Are the ids required to be consecutive? Or can I define it like

```
interface InterfaceName : IDispatch
{
  [id(1)] HRESULT FunA(...);
  [id(3)] HRESULT FunB(...);
  [id(5)] HRESULT FunC(...);
}
```

Compiling the second version seems to be fine but will there occur any problems at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actual id values are arbitrary numbers. They do not have to be consecutive; they just have to be unique. Zero and negative values are, by convention, [reserved for certain special methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237818.aspx). Apart from that, there are no rules.

Comment: Does there exist any (online)reference for this rule?

Comment: For which one? For non-requirement of IDs being consecutive? You can't really expect every non-requirement to be documented - there's an infinite number of them.

Comment: Well, that's just common sense. If you were allowed two methods with the same ID, how would `IDispatch::Invoke` know which one to call? Maybe there's a piece of documentation that states this explicitly, but I'm too lazy to go hunt for it.